# R >=4.1 function notation \(x) throws error for group_map() (purrr package)

Tags: r, purrr

I want to use the short notation for functions in R version 4.1 and higher `\(x) x+1` (as encouraged by the `tidyverse` developers) with `group_map()` from the `purrr` package. It doesn't seem to work or do I do something wrong?

```r
library(purrr)

# old notation works
mtcars |>
  group_by(cyl) |>
  group_map(~ lm(mpg ~ disp + hp, data = .x))


# R version >=4.1 notation does not work
mtcars |>
  group_by(cyl) |>
  group_map(\(x) lm(mpg ~ disp + hp, data = x))`your text`
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-19 with</sup> [<sup>reprex v2.0.2</sup>](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> - Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------
#>  version  R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)
#>  os       Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32
#>  ui       RTerm
#>  language (EN)
#>  date     2023-08-19
#> 
#> - Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package     * version date (UTC) lib source
#>  purrr       * 1.0.2   2023-08-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#>  reprex        2.0.2   2022-08-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
#> 
#>  [1] C:/Users/te/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3
#>  [2] C:/Program Files/R/R-4.3.1/library
#> 
#> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Don't ignore the error it gives you: `! \`.f\` must accept at least two arguments`.

Comment: Thanks! I just didn't know what to do with the error message. @I_O gives the answers. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, sometimes the error messages might be a bit difficult to understand. Many of us are immediately familiar with them, it's generally best when there's an error you need help with ... to include the error text in your question. _This_ question was excellently framed (clear sample data, perfect code), so no real issues. But ... bottom line, if you have a question about the error text, include the error text. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function used to map groups needs to accomodate two arguments (data and group), regardless of notation. Try:

```
mtcars |>
  group_by(cyl) |>
  group_map(\(x, y) lm(mpg ~ disp + hp, data = x))
```